# Задача на многопоточность. Синхронизация читателей и писателей C#

Tags: c#

Есть "сервер" в виде статического класса.
У него есть переменная count (тип `int`) и два метода, которые позволяют эту переменную читать и писать: `GetCount()` и `AddToCount(int value)`.
К серверу стучатся множество параллельных клиентов, которые в основном читают, но некоторые добавляют значение к `count`.

Нужно реализовать `GetCount` / `AddToCount` так, чтобы:

- читатели могли читать параллельно, без выстраивания в очередь по локу;
- писатели писали только последовательно и никогда одновременно;
- пока писатели добавляют и пишут, читатели должны ждать окончания записи.

Подскажите как такое делать, или что посмотеть

Comment: Посмотрите класс ReaderWriterLockSlim, он делает именно то, что вы описали

Comment: Называйте пожалуйста свои вопросы более конкретизирвоанно, а то представьте, будет у вас 50 вопросов с одинаковым названием, и как среди них ориентироваться? А так да, вам нужен `ReaderWriterLock` или `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Comment: Поправил заголовок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Подскажите как такое делать, или что посмотеть

Смотрите код, это очень просто:

```cs
public static class MyServer
{
    private static int count;
    private static ReaderWriterLock locker = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public static void AddToCount(int value)
    {
        locker.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        count += value;
        locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }

    public static int GetCount()
    {
        locker.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        try
        {
            return count;
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Сложно придумать пример, который бы наглядно показывал, что все работает, но я попробовал поиздеваться. Пусть четные потоки пишут, а нечетные читают.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parallel.For(0, 50, i =>
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            MyServer.AddToCount(2);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(MyServer.GetCount());
    });
    Console.WriteLine(MyServer.GetCount());
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

По выводу видно, что оно выполняется несинхронно, а параллельно, выводы в консоль происходят в разное время.

```
2
8
12
10
4
6
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
38
40
36
14
12
44
16
46
18
48
30
50
Done.
```

Как бы я не пытался перенагрузить класс чтениями и записями из отдельных потоков, последнее число всегда правильно - данном случае `50`.

---

Кстати, в случае с `int` проще пользоваться атомарными операциями типа `Interlocked.Add`.

Comment: Msdn [рекомендует](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=net-5.0#remarks) использовать `ReaderWriterLockSlim` вместо `ReaderWriterLock`.

Comment: @Qwertiy а так же `SemaphoreSlim`, `ManualResetEventSlim` и прочие `Slim`. :) но я решал задачу ждя препода, который просит RWLock для `int` реализовать, что в принципе дичь. :) а в соседнем треде вообще ему `Thread.Abort` воткнул, чисто потому что он попросил `Delegate.BeginInvoke` юзать. Сегодня вечер .NET 2.0 :)

Comment: Кому интересно в этой статье есть перевод главы из книги Джозеф Албахари, ко всему, с мылсями переводчика. http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-4.html?m=1

Comment: Можно ли в этом коде изменить в методе AddToCount на Interlocked.Add(ref int count, value) и убрать locker? Повлияет ли это на GetCount?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja конечно можно и нужно, но автор в изначальном посте решает конкретную практическую задачу и получил ответ ровно по теме.

Comment: @aepot кстати, это далеко не домашнее задание, кое что посерьезнее =)

Comment: @Kalmankantaja какой вопрос - такой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Увеличение на 1:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
```

Увеличение на произвольное значение:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref count, difference);
```

Comment: @aepot, дополнил.

Comment: Сейчас я использую такой код.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class MeServer
    {
        private static int count;
        private static ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        public static void AddToCount(int value)
        {
            locker.EnterWriteLock();
            count += value;
            locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        public static int GetCount()
        {
            locker.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return count;
            }
            finally
            {
                locker.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }
```